# Custom Python gTTS voice

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have been using the gTTS module for python 3.4 to make mp3 files of spoken text. It has been working, but all of the speech is in a certain adult female voice. Is there a way to customize the voice that gTTS reads the text in?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately it does not appear you can do that. The script uses [this webpage](https://translate.google.com/) to grab voice from, and it appears all you can do is have one voice per language.

Reading the [actual source](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/blob/master/gtts/tts.py) shows that your next best bet would be to try to pass a different language that is still English (for example, en-uk). It may produce a different result that is still English but with a different dialect.

Answer (score 2):

May be possible to pass the gTTS output through Audacity and apply a change to a male-sounding voice?  gTTS I have just got going has a very good female voice, but the engine fails to read well on long sentences or unexpected words.  Still, it's the best I found for free so far, and actually is better than all the other free ones, and a good deal of the pay ones.  I just had to work out the py scripts and how to use python and later learned Anaconda is a miracle cure to what ails you.  Got my systems terminal and the pip to install gTTS properly, which I could not do prior to Anaconda.  Scripts made by people for 3.+ now run without errors trying run them in default py v2.7.  The terminal is now env 3.6.8 but also all the old py scripts still run fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you call "gtts-cli --all" from a command prompt, you can see that gTTS actually supports a lot of voices. However, you can only change the accents, and not the gender.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can customize the text in a few languages and accents. You can find the full documentation here:

[gTTS docs](https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html)

You can try the different languages and accents this way:

```
tts_obj = gTTS(text=tts, tld=tlds["South Africa"], lang=lang, slow=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do that if you want to change the language or give another accent.
`gTTS('hello', lang='en', tld='com.au')`.
where 'tld' parameter is used for accent. for more accent [check this](https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#localized-accents) .

Answer (score 1):

You can always use pyttsx3,
It defaults to male, but you can change it to female voice as well and there are a lot more parameters you can change like speed and volume. I thing gtts voice quality is slightly better still though.
Here is some documentation to get you started if you want to use it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/text-to-speech-changing-voice-in-python

Comment: Also, pyttsx3 returns the voice a lot quicker because it also uses voices on the device, as a bonus, it can be used offline. Plus, you don't have to save the audio file to play it directly from your code if you don't want to.

Comment: pyttsx3 works terrible on linux though. I am a linux user and when I searched a lot that why was the sound quality so terrible on my laptop, I got to know that it works perfectly fine on windows but not on linux.

Comment: Irrelevant answer, it is not gTTS :(, I think above answers are better as google doesn't provide control over dialect

Answer (score -1):

You can easily change the output-language by passing an second parameter when requesting a tts. So go like:

```
tts = gTTS("Say something", lang = 'XX') #replace XX with your language code
```

On the python doc website for [Google Text-to-Speech](https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#languages-gtts-lang) you can find a table with some of the language codes from a few countrys.

Comment: I think this is not what the OP is requesting in their question.